# NSOperationQueue many threads

Tags: iphone, multithreading, nsurlconnection, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

In our iPhone application we have several tabs and selecting each tab triggers network connection. In the past we were just detaching new thread for each connection. And after several very quick tab switches application was becoming unresponsive.
Now we decided to use operation queue which supposed should control number of threads and should not allow the application to become unresponsive. But now the app becomes unresponsive even with fewer quick switches (although now it recovers from unresponsiveness quicker).
I ran the app on device from xcode and paused it after several quick switches to see the number of threads. And what I have found is that there are several threads with the following stack:

```
    0 __workq_kernreturn
    2 _init_cpu_capabilities
```

Any idea what are these threads and how to get rid of them?

Answer (score 0):

One of the big benefits of using NSOperationQueue is that you can forget about threads and let the system worry about that for you. It sounds like the root of your problem is that you've got several operations running simultaneously that are no longer needed. Rather than worrying about the specific threads, consider getting those operations to terminate so that they're no longer using up computing resources.

For what it's worth, my guess is that those threads are being managed by Grand Central Dispatch. GCD will create worker threads to process blocks (and operations), and it'll be as efficient as it can about that.

Comment: That's why we decided to switch to NSOperationQueue (forget about threads and let the system worry about that). Actually, my operations don't use much CPU, they just making a NSURLConnection (synchronous) and perform callback on main thread.

Answer (score 0):

the important part of your problem does not likely lie in the internal/private implementation of worker threads. a good implementation will likely employ a thread pool because creating one thread per operation would cost a lot. operations can reuse and hold on to idle threads.

the important part (likely) lies in your use of the public apis of the implementation you have chosen.

one obvious implementation to support in this case is operation cancellation: `-[NSOperation cancel]`. when somebody navigates away from a view which has a pending/unfinished request, simply cancel it (unless you'll need the data for caching).

many implementations may also benefit by making requests less often. for example: if your server results only update about once per hour, then it doesn't make sense to request it 'about every minute'.

last point: a connection can use a worker thread itself - check the apis you are using to reduce this if it's a problem.

Comment: Actually, instead of canceling previous request I keep track of requests in progress and don't add the operation for the same request while it is in progress. I guess the threads I mentioned are pool threads (as you noted) and maybe it's reasonable to limit maxConcurrentOperationCount.

Comment: right - if they must not cancelled and may be used later, then the can be capped - bad news is, the important operation you are waiting on will not finish any sooner if you don't cancel. when downloading a bunch of images in a similar scenario, i found approximately 4 url connections got things onscreen fastest (but that model also supported cancellation).

Comment: I think cancelling the operation which is already running is not an option because the main thing the operation does is making a synchronous HTTP request. And while the HTTP request is in process canceling will not stop it. And after a response received it is not reasonable to cancel it. So, the only place I check for cancellation is before making an HTTP request.

Comment: correct. points you already made: 1) NSURLConnection supports cancellation if your request is asynchronous 2) it is also reasonable to cancel a request before it has begun. if you've capped the max number of operations, it is likely that you will be able to cancel requests before they begin in this cenario. much of this comes down to the *time* it takes to download whatever it is you are downloading. (cont)

Comment: (cont)  both are options if your download sizes are not trivial -- but it's something you'll have to measure/compare and determine what's best in your specific scenario. afaik, you still may have the option to cache the results as well.

Comment: Requests are REST API requests and the download size is not so big. Caching is not an option because the information may be updated frequently. Anyway, limiting max number of operations solves the problem to some extent.